# Automake distcheck of symlinked sources

Tags: compiling, symlink, automake, autotools

I maintain a "master" makefile for a project with many submodules, each of which has its own autotools structure. This project is tested in a number of configurations (e.g. built against different-version backends) and can be built on different platforms/architectures using the same home directory over NFS or with cross-compilers. All this is handled by taking the current source checkout (git repo clone) workspace, "cloning(*)" the source to a separate directory for current build setup and `configure`ing/`autogen`ing that clone of sources (so not polluting original checkout), and finally building it out-of-tree as nicely supported by autotools.

The "(*)cloning" part is implemented in a number of ways, such as `cp`/`tar` copying of original workspace to the "source clone", or by making a directory structure in the clone populated with relative symlinks to original files in the main workspace. And here be dragons :)

The source clone populated by natural files is self-sufficient and passes automake jobs nicely, and in particular the `dist` (and `distcheck`) ones - unlike the "symlink clone" where `make dist` apparently tarballs the relative symlinks "as is" so after un-tarring they point nowhere meaningful.

The upside of symlinks is that a developer can edit files in the workspace and rebuild all platforms in one spell, without committing them to git etc. - speeding up the dev iteration cycles (at least as long as new files are not added - just re-"make" of edited existing ones). It is also considerably less storage and time overhead than copying same files around many times.

So the question is: Is it possible to "make dist" a directory populated by relative symlinks to original sources? Perhaps some "dist hook" or other ways to override how the tarball is made? (it would be acceptable if the `dist` procedure creates real files in its dedicated subdirectory, by e.g. dereferencing source-dir symlinks)

Or is it just not doable and we cannot both have the cake and eat it? :)

(For reference, the "master" Makefile in question is at https://github.com/42ity/FTY/ )